# how to get margin of a div with it's outer html?

Tags: javascript, html, css, d3.js

i am trying to add tooltip for my d3 chart and is now having some problem with positioning.

**What i want to get is** the horizontal margin length between a div and it's father html in javascript.
you may have a look at the attached picture.

[image]

Since my page is embedded in a complex web page so i cannot get the css margin directly. But i really need that to position my tooltip.

Can anyone give me a solution?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need the JavaScript `offsetLeft` property.

From https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLElement/offsetLeft :

> The `HTMLElement.offsetLeft` read-only method returns the number of pixels that the upper left corner of the current element is offset to the left within the HTMLElement.offsetParent node.

CSS margins are not very suitable for this, because if you have floating elements or inline-blocks, it depends on the screen width how many elements are to the left of your div. So that's not calculable directly.

Comment: Yes i finally found jQuery.offset() method that fit my need. I have tried HTMLElement.offsetLeft but for the same div it's result is different from that of jQuery.offset() and jQuery is correct. I am not sure why.

Comment: Oh... if my answer was incorrect, feel free to add your own answer and accept that!

Comment: i think the two methods are the same... let me study them and modify the answer today later